# Abstract - override methods return an error of "cannot convert void to bool"

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a code that calculates the perimeter of the shapes in the process of learning abstract classes. So I created an abstract base class "Figure" and derive it with shape names. I use one method to override it with different implentations.
PS: I know returning the methods would be easier and I could create a variable like "int sum" to store and print, but I'd like to use the way in the code I've given to grasp the problem.
However, there is something wrong I can't see since yesterday.
edit: "cannot explicitly convert void to bool" error are on lines 16 and 17 which are
Figure rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 6);
Figure triangle = new Triangle(4, 8, 3);

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSHARP3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Figure rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 6);
            Figure triangle = new Triangle(4, 8, 3);

            Console.WriteLine(rectangle.Perimeter());
            Console.WriteLine(triangle.Perimeter());
        }
    }
    abstract class Figure
    {
        //define abstract method Perimeter
        public abstract void Perimeter();
    }
    class Rectangle : Figure
    {
        public int width;
        public int height;
        public Rectangle(int width, int height)
        {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }
        //override Perimeter method for rectangle
        public override void Perimeter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(2 * (width + height));
        }

    }
    class Triangle : Figure
    {
        public int side1;
        public int side2;
        public int side3;
        public Triangle(int s1, int s2, int s3)
        {
            this.side1 = s1;
            this.side2 = s2;
            this.side3 = s3;
        }

        //override Perimeter method for triangle
        public override void Perimeter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(side1 + side2 + side3);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing `Console.WriteLine` on a method that returns nothing (and uses Console.WriteLine itself). Best fix: just return the value from that Perimeter method instead of printing it

Comment: Please tell us what is going wrong. Compile error? Runtime error? In short: What fails when exactly. Your Console commands are looking strange. Normally you would have to calculate the result first and the run the `WriteLine` passing in the `result.ToString()`.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thank you for the answer. The best solution for that is returning, yes. However, I want to use a void method and print it after calculation.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt I think it's an compile error because it says "cannot convert void to bool" in the first two lines after Main method, "Figure rectangle...." on those lines. I should add that to the topic. Thanks. btw, I am looking for a way without passing if possible. That's the issue.

Comment: @oceilot: There's no need to add "Solved" to the title, accepting an answer with the "check mark" (which you already did) is enough. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311829/87698

Comment: @Heinzi Oh okay. I thought I should edit it so as for people not to waste time solving this. Duly noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line `Console.WriteLine(rectangle.Perimeter());` you are calling Console.WriteLine on a method that returns nothing. In fact that Perimeter() is doing a Console.WriteLine itself!

The best fix would be to return a value from that method:

```
abstract class Figure
{
    public abstract int Perimeter();
}
```

and of course fix the actual implementations by replacing the Console.WriteLine with a `return`.

If you really really want that method to do its own printing, then just call the method: `rectangle.Perimeter();` No extra Console.WriteLine needed, as that method already takes care of it (and there is nothing to print anyway).

---

As to why the compiler's error message (CS1503) mentions "bool": Console.WriteLine has multiple overloads and none of them fit. The compiler chooses one (apparently with a `bool` argument) and complains that your argument (type void) doesn't fit.

Comment: This is very explanatory for me. Appreciate it. I am still learning and explanations like this are so useful. I will try to fix this again considering that comment.